# Is there a way to change Default Nontype Template Parameters when overloading `std::ostream` operator?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  template <int bias = 5>
  void print() {
    std::cout << bias << std::endl;
  }
};

template <int bias = 5>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Foo &foo) {
  return os << bias;
}

int main() {
  Foo a;
  a.print();
  a.print<>();
  a.print<1>();
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

By showing this code, I mean, despite the terrible implementation, is there a way to change the default parameter `5` **to output `Foo a` using `std::cout << a << std::endl` format** and keeping the `struct` unchanged ?

Comment: please include expected output, there are too many places where one could pick a different value for `bias` in the code and it isnt clear where you want to "change the default"

Comment: Fixed. I wonder if this version of clarification can be accepted qwq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a template parameter when you call `operator <<` like an operator.

```
std:cout << a << std::endl;
```

But you can add the template parameter if you call `operator <<` like a function. Please note that as the return type is `std::ostream &` you can call more `operator <<` in operator style syntax.

```
operator<< <3>(std::cout, a) << std::endl;
```

It would also be possible to add more `operator <<` calls before output of `a`, but that all doesn't look as nice as your original calls.

```
operator<< <3>(std::cout << "a=", a) << std::endl;
```

Another option that works with the original chaining of `operator <<` works by introducing a helper class.

```
template<int Bias>
struct Biased {
    Biased(Foo& foo) :_foo{ foo } {}
    Foo& _foo;
};

template<int Bias>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Biased<Bias>& biased) {
    return os << Bias;
}

std::cout << "a=" << Biased<42>(a) << std::endl;
```

Please note that I added `_foo` to `Biased` so that the `operator <<` for `Biased` could also print the content of `_foo` if desired (which does not happen in this code here).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation! Certainly, this problem can be fixed with better implementation, but I just wonder if there's a way to call like normal `std::cout << x << std::endl` format. Anyway, thanks a a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way - the operator can be called explicitly, which allows for the full template instantiation syntax:

```
operator<<<3>(std::cout, a);
```

Not quite that readable, though. In order to restore the previous behavior (except the value of `bias`), you can add an additional

```
std::cout << '\n';
```

or continue using chaining, see [Werner Henze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63189548/9593596).

Comment: am I missing something? whats the problem with chaining? One can still write `operator<<<3>(std::cout, a) << '\n';`. Not saying that it is pretty, but it chains like usual

Comment: @idclev463035818 You're right, I oversaw it. But as it's in WernerHenze's answer, I didn't want to add it to mine.

Comment: yes read his answer after yours. May I suggest to change wording from "doesn't work well, so ... you need" to something along the line of "leads to obfuscated syntax, so ... you can".

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, you may suggest the wording change :) Just a sec...

Comment: Yes, that's one of the ways, and it's of use in code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In such case I prefer provide a nice tool which make intention clear.

```cpp
template<int bias>
struct Prefer
{
    Prefer(Foo& foo) :foo{foo} {}

    std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os) const {
        return operator<< <bias>(os, foo);
    }

private:
    Foo& foo;
};

template <int bias>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Prefer<bias> &pref) {
  return pref.print(os);
}

int main() {
  Foo a;
  a.print();
  a.print<>();
  a.print<1>();
  std::cout << Prefer<2>(a) << std::endl;
  std::cout << Prefer<10>(a) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/j49Eo9

Comment: Yes! This implementation is neat too!